# Add "selectable" commas between multiple <span> items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add some commas between a list of  items.

I know that you can do that by using :

```css
.comma:not(:last-of-type)::after{
    content: ", ";
}
```

```html
<span class="comma">A</span>
<span class="comma">B</span>
<span class="comma">C</span>
```

But with this technic the commas are not really written (you can't select them). I need to be able to select them because I then copy the text in the clipboard :)

Any ideas on how to do this (with css or js) ?

Comment: your commas do not exist in DOM, so they cannot be selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all but the last `.comma` span, and then add a comma to their [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText):

```js
spans = document.querySelectorAll('.comma:not(:last-of-type)')

spans.forEach(span => span.innerText = span.innerText + ', ')
```

```html
<span class="comma">A</span>
<span class="comma">B</span>
<span class="comma">C</span>
```

If you want to avoid placing commas after "empty" spans, you could check the `length` of the `innerText` before appending a comma:

```js
spans = document.querySelectorAll('.comma:not(:last-of-type)')

spans.forEach(span => span.innerText = span.innerText + (span.innerText.length ? ', ' : ''))
```

```html
<span class="comma">A</span>
<span class="comma"></span>
<span class="comma">C</span>
```

And if the spans might contain whitespace that you want to ignore, just `trim` the values first:

```js
spans = document.querySelectorAll('.comma:not(:last-of-type)')

spans.forEach(span => span.innerText = span.innerText.trim() + (span.innerText.trim().length ? ', ' : ''))
```

```html
<span class="comma">A </span>
<span class="comma">   </span>
<span class="comma"> C</span>
```

Comment: It works perfectly thanks ! But do you know how to avoid that if a span is empty there is still a comma ? :)

Comment: @MykAdo I've edited the answer to cover that case (as well as whitespace you might want to ignore)